# How do you start the development server when starting a new Django project

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to start a new Django project for the first time and I can't seem to figure out how to run the server. On the tutorial page for Django it says

> Change into the outer mysite directory, if you haven’t already, and run the following commands:

```
...\> py manage.py runserver
```

When I do this, nothing happens. I tried running the command from the mysite directory and from the Django test folder I made for the project.

Here is a screenshot :

[image: screenshot of cmd terminal]

The Django tutorial says I should be expecting this result:

```
 Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

February 19, 2021 - 15:50:53
Django version 3.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Before I did this I installed pipenv by following [this guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) and followed the guide all the way up to "Next Steps".

I have also attached a screen shot of what the folder looks like:

[image: Picture of Django project folder]
[image: mysite folder]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `manage.py` file should exist under `DjangoTest` folder. I do not see this file in your screenshot.

Comment: The `manage.py` file is in the mysite folder. I have added an edit with a new screenshot. Does this help?

Comment: You should navigate to inside of the mysite folder where the manage.py exists and execute py manage.py runserver there.

Comment: @prathapsagar I just gave that another try and still the same result

Answer (score 0):

From the initial command prompt image shared, it appeared you tried starting the server from `c:\Users\Timo\DesktopTest>` which doesn't `manage.py`. It obvious from the last two screenshots that, `manage.py` reside in a sub directory of `DesktopTest`.

Change directory to `c:\Users\Timo\DesktopTest\mysite>, then start the dev server.

**Note: You should make sure your virtual environment is active**

Though, it appears the you haven't activated pipenv. And if this is correct, python may not be aware you have any package called Django outside the virtual environment.
To activate pipenv, from `c:\Users\Timo\DesktopTest>` run the command `pipenv shell`, if it runs successfully, your currently cmd path should look something like this
`(some strings)c:\Users\Timo\DesktopTest>`
then you can be sure your virtual environment is active. you may the CD to your django project directory and do `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Thank you for making that clear for me, I was unsure which directory to run the command and kept trying to run the command from both. I now went into the directory you suggested and then ran the command `pipenv shell`  (to activate the virtual environment, I hope this is correct), and then I tried the runserver command again. It then gave my the following error:
`ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`

I checked the environment variable and don't see PYTHONPATH

Comment: Do I need to add that to the environment variable or did I not make the virtual environment active when i used  `pipenv shell`

Comment: Well it may or may not be the problem. To get things straight follow these steps 1. Create a new directory. 2. Launch command prompt from the new directory 3. Run `pipenv install django` 4. Once installation is done, run `pipenv shell` to activate you virtual environment 5. Run `django-admin startproject mysite` 6. Change directory to mysite `cd mysite` 7.Start Dev server `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: THANK YOU SO FLIPPEN MUCH! This worked! Will I need to do this process every time I start a project?

Comment: Most likely for a new project. But to launch an existing project, you only need to access cmd from the project directory, start virtual env., and start Dev server.

Comment: Thank you for all your help @Seyi. It's been very much appreciated